# Perl Division Program

Tags: perl

I'm learning Perl and have come across this question

> Write a Perl program that reads in two numbers and does the following:
>   It prints Error: can't divide by zero if the second number is 0.

If I enter the second number as zero, I'm getting an error

> `Illegal division by zero at ./divide.pl line 13, <STDIN> line 2.`

I'm using the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

## Divide by zero program

print("Enter the first number: \n");
$input1 = <STDIN>;
chomp ($input);

print ("Enter the second number: \n");
$input2 = <STDIN>;
chomp ($input2);

$answer = $input1/$input2;

if ($input2 == 0)
{
 print("Error: can't divide by zero \n");
}

print("The answer is $answer \n");
```

Comment: You need test the values of the inputs *before* doing the division

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as being a "simple typographical error". Help with basic program flow isn't likely to be sought by a significant number of others. Quite why this question has two votes I cannot imagine.

Comment: This is a most legitimate beginner question and it should not be closed. [It is not at all obvious](https://books.google.com/books?id=JTYPKxug49IC&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&) *a priori*, that division by zero will interrupt program flow so that any subsequent instructions would not be executed. The OP was tempted to do the division instead of deciding whether the result of the division would be an approximation of a real number. So, at most, there is a misunderstanding of the original assignment, but that does not invalidate the OP's question.

Answer (score 6):

You need to perform your check before doing the division. You also need skip doing the division entirely if the check is true.

```
if ($input2 == 0) {
    print("Error: can't divide by zero\n");
} else {
    my $answer = $input1/$input2;
    print("The answer is $answer\n");    
}
```

By the way, ALWAYS ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );` in your programs.

Answer (score 4):

Stolen from Sinan's comment (because sometimes we forget that things we know aren't known): You're seeing that message because Perl 5 (along with many other languages) doesn't handle [division by zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero). The interpreter tries to do it with no safeguards and having done so, gives up with a `die`. Your program immediately stops. You never make it to your check.

---

Much of the practice of programming is checking input when you get them. Instead of checking later, validate them as soon as you receive them. You can also check that both inputs are actually numbers. [Scalar::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) comes with Perl and has a `looks_like_number` subroutine that does that for you:

```
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

print("Enter the first number: ");
chomp( my $numerator = <STDIN> );
die "$numerator doesn't look like a number!\n" 
    unless looks_like_number($numerator);

print ("Enter the second number: ");
chomp( my $denominator = <STDIN> );
die "$denominator doesn't look like a number!\n" 
    unless looks_like_number($denominator);
die "Can't divide by zero!\n" if $denominator == 0;

my $answer = $numerator/$denominator;
print "$numerator / $denominator = $answer\n";
```

Do that for a bit and you start to realize that you've repeated yourself. You could move that to a subroutine. Once abstracted away you can adjust `get_number` for any sort of validation that you like:

```
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my $numerator   = get_number();
my $denominator = get_number();
die "Can't divide by zero!\n" if $denominator == 0;

my $answer = $numerator/$denominator;
print "$numerator / $denominator = $answer\n";

sub get_number {
    print("Enter a number: ");
    chomp( my $number = <STDIN> );
    die "$number doesn't look like a number!\n"
        unless looks_like_number($number);
    return $number;
    }
```

And, I like to leave the newline off of prompts so I type my input right after the message:

```
$ perl zero.pl  
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 5
4 / 5 = 0.8

$ perl zero.pl  
Enter a number: Llama
Llama doesn't look like a number!
```